# Abstract property with JsonIgnore is being serialized (Json.NET)

Tags: json.net

I have the following setup:

```
public abstract class A
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public abstract Type Foo { get; }
}

public abstract class B : A
{
    public override Type Foo { get { return typeof(D); } }
}

public class C : B
{
}

public abstract class D
{
}
```

My problem is that when I serialize an instance of C via the following:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instanceOfC, serializationSettings));
```

The resulting JSON includes an entry for property Foo. Is this the expected result?

My `serializationSettings` are as follows:

```
JsonSerializerSettings _serializationSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor
};
```

Edit:  Using Json.NET 6.0.0 and .NET 4.5.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem with the code you've given.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/aEUy3p

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and I've solved it by specifying a "ContractResolver" property of JsonSerializerSettings like this (initialize all necessary properties for you ):

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.None,
            ContractResolver = new PublicNotInternalPropertiesCamelCaseContractResolver()

        };
```

And here is my PublicNotInternalPropertiesCamelCaseContractResolver:

```
public class PublicNotInternalPropertiesCamelCaseContractResolver : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    #region Overrides of DefaultContractResolver

    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
    {
        var members = base
            .GetSerializableMembers(objectType)
            .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttribute<InternalAttribute>() == null)
            .ToList();

        return members;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I've had to create an attribute "InternalAttribute", because this solution does not work with JsonIgnoreAttribute for some reasons:

```
public class InternalAttribute : Attribute
{

}
```

And I use it like this:

```
public abstract class RavenDbEntity
{
    private string _dbKey;

    [Internal]
    public string DbKey
    {
        get { return _dbKey; }
        set
        {
            _dbKey = value;
            Id = int.Parse(value.Split('/')[1]);
        }
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

So the output JSON will be without DbKey property